# iPhone 5 non-responsive when ringing

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.4. No third-party software like apps are installed --- the device is all but fresh from the factory.

The device gets non-responsive sometimes when I get an incoming call (about one call in 20) -- the phone keeps ringing but it's impossible to answer it because the touch screen won't respond. After clicking the lock button (on top of the device) a few times, the call is lost and the device gets back to normal, which makes me think this is an iOS bug and not a hardware problem.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

**Edit:** After using the phone more, I've noticed that the UI may suffer hiccups in many more situations (for instance when texting somebody a message); the phone freezes and becomes unresponsive for a few seconds. This behavior is obviously most annoying when you can't answer incoming calls.

Comment: Is **all** the screen responseless or just the lower are?

Comment: @Thecafremo: I have tried pushing every visible UI element when the device has entered non-responsive mode to try to provoke some kind of response from the phone, but to no avail. These elements are all located in the lower area.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restarting and resetting the phone seems to have solved the problems. It now works like a charm. It remains to be seen if the problems will resurface; I guess another reset will be neccessary then.

I have no apps installed, so this seems like an iOS 6 issue.

Comment: After upgrading the phone to iOS7, the problem is gone. This further strenghens the case that this is an iOS6 issue.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't ring out or accept incoming calls on new Iphone 5 as it had become unresponsive, there are very few apps installed on phone as it is new. Turned power off and back on and phone works again. Hope problem is not recurring.

Comment: Are you using iOS7? I have not had any problems since upgrading from iOS6.